# How can I get a FileChooser to populate a TextView during a TableRow creation?

Tags: java, android, tablerow, filechooser

**Problem:** I'm having trouble getting a `FileChooser` class to populate a `TextView` during a `TableRow` creation. I receiving a `Invocation Exception` in the Android created "looper.java" which appears to be caused by a variable `tagTrace=0` being read as "!=0". So, I'm not sure how I may be able to workaround it.

**What I'm trying to do:** I'm trying to build on to an existing process. When a user clicks on a "+" button on the header row of a `TableLayout`, it creates a row with two views: a "Delete" (-) `Button` in row.child(0) and a `TextView` in row.child(1). It does this successfully. There is a `Singleton` class that manages various types of `TableRow` creations for all the app `Actiities`.

On one particular `Activity` exists a Files `TableLayout`. I want the user, when clicking on the "+" buttion I described above, to launch a `FileChooser` to capture a file path and populate that path to the `TextView` child of the row it is creating. However, I'm running into the issue above.

**The Looper.java Bug (I think) causing the invocation exception**

[image: Looper Bug]

**The FileChooser**

```
    public class FileChooser extends AppCompatActivity {
        private String fileName;
        private String filePath;
        private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> resultLauncher;
    
        public FileChooser(){
            //if(intent==null) Toast.makeText(null, "Intent is Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            this.resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK && result.getData() != null){
                    Uri uri = result.getData().getData();
                    filePath = uri.getPath();
                }
            });
        }
    
        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }
    
        public String getFilePath() {
            return filePath;
        }
    
        public ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> getResultLauncher() {
            return resultLauncher;
        }

}
```

**The Method within the Singleton creating the TableRow** The "!bold"

```
public static TableRow setupFilesTableRow(Context context, TableLayout table, String fileID, String fileName, boolean bold) {
    TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
    if(bold) {
        row.addView(setupFilesAddRowButton(context, table));
        row.addView(addRowTextViewToTable(context, fileName, true));
    }
    if (!bold) {
        row.addView(setupDeleteRowButton(context, table));
        
            // Intent and FileChooser to capture a filePath
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            fileChooser.getResultLauncher().launch(intent);

            // Adding a TextView child to the new TableRow with the captured filePath from the FileChooser
            row.addView(addRowTextViewToTable(context, fileChooser.getFilePath(), false));
            //row.setClickable(true);
        
    }
    return row;
}
```

Comment: You have at least three problems here. You are calling `getFilePath()` shortly after calling `launch()`, and the user will not have chosen anything yet. Also, `getFilePath()` will not return a file path, and `getFileName()` will not return a file name, as a `Uri` is not a file. Plus, you never populate `fileName`, so it will always be `null`.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Ok, I see what you are saying and I hadn't really gotten that far because the `launch(intent)` was failing beforehand on the `looper`. I also agree on the the inappropriateness of the `URI`, I was planning to change it to `File`. Ironically, with exception of creating a class to contain it all, this was an online tutorial and it worked in a separate application test, the only difference was launching from a Singleton method.

Comment: "I also agree on the the inappropriateness of the URI, I was planning to change it to File." -- you are not working with files. In terms of your main problem, you are trying to create an instance of an activity directly (`new FileChooser()`, with `FileChooser` inheriting from `Activity`). That will not work. `FileChooser`, if it is not actually an activity, should not extend `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, I better understand your point now.  Most of my experience with Activities and Intents have been simple transitions, I haven't had to do a lot on moving back and forth between the same activities for results. Lot's I need to go back, review and relearn on the combination of Activities, Intents and the newer `ActivityResultLauncher` which seems to be replacing the `startActivityForResult`. Those combined are a weak point in my learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use an embedded `Button` within the `TableLayout` which was causing issues (see above), I simply created an "ADD" button outside the tablelayout to launch the `FileChooser` and add a `TableRow` with the captured information. Due to being unfamiliar with Android and still learning the platform, this was my solution, and was probably more logically understood from a user perspective.

```
    private void setupOnClickActions() {
        btnAddFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("*/*");
                resultLauncher.launch(intent);

            }
        });
}
```

---

```
    intentLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result ->{
                if(result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    assert result.getData() != null;
                    Sources src = result.getData().getParcelableExtra("source");
                    if(src == null){
                        PopupDialog.AlertMessage(AddNote.this, "Error: Author Choice",
                                "An issue occurred and an author choice was not returned.");
                        return;
                    }
                    setSourceDetails(src);
                    selectedSourceID = src.getSourceID();
                }

            }
    );
```

---

Answer (score 1):

> > FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

You cannot create a new activity with the `new` operator.

Activities have to be started using an intent.

Comment: I see, I didn't think of that obviously,  that make sense.